# Is it possible to train the offline Google speech to text engine with own phrases?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have an Android app which uses the offline Google Speech To Text engine. I want it to recognize addresses, but it tries to convert them to common words. I need some boost for a list of addresses. It's not a duplicate of [Train google speech to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996268/train-google-speech-to-text) because I need it to work offline. It would be optimal if I add a map with phrases and a boost value in a class directly in the app.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

afaik google doesn't allow you, but you may find a way with picovoice rhino https://picovoice.ai/platform/rhino/ and here maps https://www.here.com apis. both have free tier and pretty generous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).